# Each item of the array must loop and show message for some time (duration) and repeat msg each value of delay

Tags: javascript, array, closure

Is there a better way to loop item of an array using `forEach` and make repeat it using `setTimout`/`Interval` or something else?

I need that each item of the array was repeated each value of delay for some time (duration):

```
const arr = [
  { delay: 1_000, duration: 3_000, msg: "Hello World" }, //repeat 3 times msg for 3 sec
  { delay: 2_000, duration: 4_000, msg: "Sup?" } //repeat 2 times msg for 3 sec
];
```

[Here is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/to-loop-an-element-of-array-dm1eq?file=/src/index.js:140-154) and here is the code but I think it's a difficult solution:

```js
const arr = [
  { delay: 1_000, duration: 3_000, msg: "Hello World" }, //repeat msg each sec for 3 sec
  { delay: 2_000, duration: 4_000, msg: "Sup?" } //repeat msg each 2 sec for 4 sec
];

class LoopElem {
  constructor(configs) {
    this.count = 0;
    this.sumDelay = 0;
    this.toLoopElem(configs);
  }

  toLoopElem = (configs) => {
    const that = this;
    const { delay, duration, msg } = configs[that.count];
    setTimeout(function request() {
      that.sumDelay += delay;
      console.log(msg); // each delay shows msg
      if (that.sumDelay >= duration) {
        that.sumDelay = 0;
        that.count += 1;
        // if array have already no item stop repeat it
        if (!configs[that.count]) {
          return null;
        }
        setTimeout(that.toLoopElem, configs[that.count].delay, configs);
        return null;
      }
      setTimeout(request, delay);
    }, delay);
  };
}

new LoopElem(arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect the code can be improved by making it less complex and convoluted. As posted the `LoopElem` class avoids creating variables in global scope by using instance object properties and  function scoped variables in the `toLoopElem` class method.

The option to avoid creating global variables by rewriting the code using nested functions without using JavaScript classes has been covered in  [BlindMan67's excellent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263007/85177) which I won't revisit here.

What I want to bring up is that if the `LoopElem` class needs to have additional methods added to it, say to stop, rewind, pause or fast forward messages as you would in a media player, there is a case for using a class definition. However, you would call a message `play` method for outside code, not from within the constructor.

Two points about the question first:

1. `Array.prototype.forEach` is a synchronous method which calls its function argument parameters in quick succession for each array entry - you can't delay calls between entries. So it won't be useful for this case.
2. `setInterval` is no more accurate that `setTimeout` and internally uses `setTimeout` code without creating a new timer id to return to the caller. Since different messages use different delays between repeats, using `setInterval` could make the code more rather than less complex.

Here's a `LoopBox` class  example that creates a message player with two methods: `play` and `stop`. The problem of `this` vs `that` usage is solved by using an arrow function for `repeat` to access object instance `this` values, and making `playLoop` an ordinary function instead of an arrow function.

```js
class LoopBox {
  constructor(loops) {
    this.loops = loops;
    this.loopIndex = -1;
    this.timerId = 0;
  }
  play() {
    if( ++this.loopIndex < this.loops.length) {
      this.playLoop( this.loops[ this.loopIndex ]);
    }
    else {
      this.stop();
    }
  }
  playLoop(loop) { 
      let sumDelay = 0;  
      const repeat = () => {
        console.log( loop.msg);
        sumDelay += loop.delay;
        if( sumDelay >= loop.duration) {
          this.play();  
        }
        else {
          this.timerId = setTimeout( repeat, loop.delay);
        }
      }
      this.timerId = setTimeout( repeat, loop.delay);
  }
  stop() {
      clearTimeout( this.timerId);
      this.loopIndex = -1;
  }
}
const looper = new LoopBox( [
  { delay: 1_000, duration: 3_000, msg: "Hello World" }, //repeat msg each sec for 3 sec
  { delay: 2_000, duration: 4_000, msg: "Sup?" } //repeat msg each 2 sec for 4 sec
]);

looper.play();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Source code is too complex

The code is way too complex for what you are doing
Mainly due to all of the superfluous code.

#### Not needed

- all the `return null`,
- all of the class code for object `loopElm`
- `that = this` (you should never need to do that!!)

and with some odd naming it is very hard to decipher your intent

### Rewrite

The following does the same but without all the additional source code complexity.

I changed the duration value to repeat. This value can be calculated from `duration / delay`  but I don't see the point

```
function timeEventsCycle(timing) {
    var count = 0;        
    next();
    function next(info) {
        count = count <= 0 ? (info = timing.shift())?.repeat - 1 : count - 1;
        if (info) {
            console.log(info.msg)
            setTimeout(next, info.delay, info);
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>As timeout can be very inaccurate you can track the time and adjust the timeout to keep as close as possible to the timing you want.</strike>

<strike>The next rewrite keeps the times as close a possible to the requested times by adjusting the timeout to speed up if falling behind schedule.</strike>

Updated and fixed version

```js
function timeEventsCycle(timing) {
    const getCount = info => info && (info.duration / info.delay) - 1;
    var count = -1;    
    (function next(info) {
        count >= 0 && console.log(info.msg );
        count = count <= 0 ? getCount(info = timing.shift()) : count - 1;
        info && setTimeout(next, info.delay, info);
    })();
}

console.log("start")
timeEventsCycle([
  { delay: 1000, duration: 3000, msg: "Hello World" }, 
  { delay: 2000, duration: 4000, msg: "Sup?" } 
]);
```

<sub>**NOTE:** the log output `"start"` is only to show the delay between starting and first message.</sub>

Comment: **- all of the class code for object loopElm**   So? It has to be a class, it's a condition  
**-that = this (you should never need to do that!!)**
Why?  
1. First "Sup" shows in 1 sec but should be in 2 sec  2. We can't change the data

Comment: Use `Function.bind` rather than `that = this` eg the timeout callback `setTimeout(function request() { /* code */ }, ` becomes  `setTimeout((function request() { /* code */ }).bind(this), `

Comment: got it, thank you